# I want to refer to a variable in another python script

Tags: python, variables, import

A variable `AA` is in `aaa.py`. I want to use this variable in my other python file `bbb.py`

How do I access this variable?

Comment: Read about python imports. [This](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) may be useful, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [modules!](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

In `aaa.py`:

```
AA = 'Foo'
```

In `bbb.py`:

```
import aaa
print aaa.AA # Or print(aaa.AA) for Python 3
# Prints Foo
```

Or this works as well:

```
from aaa import AA
print AA
# Prints Foo
```

Comment: No idea, this is the most relevant answer.

Comment: Mine was downvoted as well, although I was only pointing out an alternative approach…

Comment: Is `bbb.py` in the same directory as `aaa.py`?

Comment: @user2351602 As suggested in the other answer, you'd have to modify your sys.path variable, if bbb.py is not in the same folder.

Comment: It has more problem.. I put togather in same folder, but bbb.py execute all lines in aaa.py

Comment: @user2351602 What exactly did you put in bbb.py? And also, what kind of stuff is in aaa.py?

Comment: @user2351602 If you import it, it will get executed. Without execution, the variable is not set at all, so you have to do this. Besides that, look at my answer, maybe that's a solution for your problem, since we do not know what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can import it; this will execute the whole script though.

```
from aaa import AA
```

Answer (score 1):

In your file `bbb.py`, add the following:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/aaa.py/folder/")
from aaa import AA
```

Also would suggest reading more about Python modules and how `import` works. [Official Documentation on Modules.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

Answer (score -1):

Although importing is the best approach (like poke or Haidro wrote), here is another workaround, if you're generating data with one script and want to access them in another, without executing "`bbb.py`". So if you're dealing with large lists/dicts, this approach works well, although it's an overkill if you simply trying to interchange a string or a number…

Besides that, you should describe your problem more detailed, since importing variables from another script is kind of hacky and may not be the way to go.

So here are two functions, the first one (`dumpobj`) dumps a variable (string, number, tuple, list, dict sets whatever) to a file, the second one (`loadobj`) reads it in. I decided to use `json`, since the data files are human readable.

You may want to try that, if you need it often:

```
import json


def dumpobj(the_object, filename) :
    """
    Dumps the_object to filename via json. Use loadobj(filename)
    to get it back.

         >>> from tgio import dumpobj, loadobj
         >>> foo = {'bar':42, 'narf':'fjoord', 23:[1,2,3,4,5]}
         >>> dumpobj(foo, 'foo.var')
         >>> bar = loadobj('foo.var')
         >>> bar
         {u'narf': u'fjoord', u'bar': 42, u'23': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
    """
    try:
        with open(filename):
            print(filename + " exists, I'll will overwrite it.")
    except IOError:
        print(filename + ' does not exist. Creating it...')

    f = open(filename, 'w')
    json.dump(the_object, f)
    f.close()

def loadobj(filename) :
    """
    Retrieves dumped data (via json - see dumpobj) from filename.

         >>> from tgio import loadobj, dumpobj
         >>> foo = {'bar':42, 'narf':'fjoord', 23:[1,2,3,4,5]}
         >>> dumpobj(foo, 'foo.var')
         >>> bar = loadobj('foo.var')
         >>> bar
         {u'narf': u'fjoord', u'bar': 42, u'23': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
    """
    try:
        with open(filename):
            print("Reading object from file " + filename)
    except IOError:
        print(filename + ' does not exist. Returning None.')
        return None

    f = open(filename, 'r')
    the_object = json.load(f)
    f.close
    return the_object
```

See the usage examples in the docstrings!

Comment: Waaay too complicated for the problem at hand.

Comment: It totally depends on what he's up to…

Comment: …reading in variables from another script may be a sign for a bad design.